# Are there a database of name written in english?

Tags: dataset, dynamically-generated

I am making football game. And I want to random generate name in my game. So I need a name database or name generator

But normal name generator are writing name in their language so I can't use that

It could be a list of names then I could write script to import. But I want it written in english and have nationality. At least 100 per nation and cover all nation FIFA used

Thanks for helping in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a generator like http://www.generatedata.com/

Example generated data: (Country, MaleName Surname)

```
country|name
Sudan|Malcolm Bartlett
Australia|Solomon Soto
Curaçao|Ronan Vasquez
Sint Maarten|Amal Russell
Paraguay|Jack Singleton
Pakistan|Wyatt Cortez
Guinea-Bissau|Brock Hayden
Germany|Quamar Collier
French Guiana|Xander Kline
```

It's not perfect, but maybe a start.